# Deleting the `f` tag

Tags: support, tagging

The [`f` tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/f/info) was creted today, along with [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/560214/134805). My guess is that it was created by mistake. It should be deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it's the only question using the [f](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/f) tag, removing it from that question (I've just submitted a suggested edit for that) will automatically delete the tag when the tag pruning script runs (once every 24 hours): [What *currently* happens to zombie tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40724/295232)

Comment: Thank you. I would have edited the question myself if I new about that 24 hours rule.